# preserve decimal places and vertically align decimals in output table

Tags: r, format

I'm looking for recommended ways of using baseR or any library to achieve this type of exported table format. I tried some functions in `library(prettyR)` but was unsuccessful.

```
col1 <- rep("a", 4)
col2 <- c(0.60, 1234.55, 678.90, -999.00)
df <- data.frame(col1,col2)

write.table(df, "df.dat", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

# intended *df.dat* format - decimal places preserved and decimals vertically aligned
#col1    col2
#a        0.60
#a     1234.55
#a      678.90
#a     -999.00
```

thank you!

Comment: `knitr::kable`?

Comment: Another alternative, `df$col2 <- sprintf("%0.02f", df$col2)`, then `sprintf(paste0("%0", max(nchar(df$col2)), "s"), df$col2)`.

Comment: thanks @r2evans for both! the second worked perfectly and I'll look into the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few alternatives, depending on your needs:

### Use `print.data.frame`

This benefits from (or is encumbered by, depending on your perspective) `options("digits")` and perhaps others.

```r
out <- paste(capture.output(print(df, row.names=F)), collapse = "\n")
writeLines(out, "df.dat")
```

File contents:

```
 col1    col2
    a    0.60
    a 1234.55
    a  678.90
    a -999.00
```

### Manual stringification/alignment

```r
df$col2 <- sprintf("%0.02f", df$col2)
df$col2 <- sprintf(paste0("%0", max(nchar(df$col2)), "s"), df$col2)
write.table(df, "df.dat", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

File contents (notice column-alignment is not being handled perfectly):

```
col1 col2
a    0.60
a 1234.55
a  678.90
a -999.00
```

### `knitr::kable`

If this is for looks, then perhaps one of the `kable` variants will work:

```r
knitr::kable(df)
# |col1 |    col2|
# |:----|-------:|
# |a    |    0.60|
# |a    | 1234.55|
# |a    |  678.90|
# |a    | -999.00|
```

Comment: all great to know. use case for me is for making a data card format input file with strict formatting requirements.

Comment: easy change if `col1 <- c(1,2,3,10)` (having both one and two character elements)?

Comment: Which of the three options above are you currently trying to use?

Comment: Okay, so the issue with that is the alignment within a column, as `col1` indicates. If you use `write.table(..., sep="\t")`, then it may look better, but may not be perfect.

Comment: got it - I'll fix my `col1`.